# Request A Code button,

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I run an amazon review site, and I need a button that will request a code from a text file that is uploaded by the seller.

What I am needing to know is how can this be done using HTML if possible.

I am trying to use this example:

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But instead of the pre-filled text. It will display only the code that is in the txt file that was upload by the seller. Only that members can see and be issue a random code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're trying to request data from an external site after a button was clicked.

In this case, HTML can't really do this on it's own since it's just a layout and markup language.

What you're looking for is something along the lines of an AJAX request which is used with javascript or some jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
The data would located on the site via a txt file.

Would u happen to know how to do this are point me in the right direction

Comment: The site that holds the txt file would need to have an API/a means of accepting your request and responding to it. If you've not worked with javascript or jQuery before I'd read up on any of the descriptions/walk throughs at w3 http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ . If you're looking to get more indepth, I'd recommend treehouse (teamtreehouse.com), they have a really great lesson group on js, jquery and ajax in particular.

Comment: Read the link you sent,And i get the overall reason what ajax does,However i am still stumped on how to code this